# How to rename Django settings directory?

Tags: django

By default when creating a new project in Django with:

`apps/# django-admin startproject example`

it creates a root directory using the project name:

`/apps/example/`

and inside this root directory it creates a directory with the same name, containing the settings files for the whole project:

`apps/example/example/`

How can I rename the settings directory from `apps/example/example/` to `apps/example/config/`?

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution would be as follows:

1. Create a project directory using OS

   $ mkdir myproject
2. Enter newly created directory:$

   $ cd myproject
3. Run the command:

   $ django-admin startproject config .